# Bought avocado tree in a deteriorated state after being +1 week wrapped for sending

Tags: trees, avocado

I bought a grafted avocado plant (it ended up being more like a small tree). The main problem is that **it was sent on the 24th of March** (Friday). **It should have arrived on the 28th** but it seems they had technical problems and **it did not arrive to me until the 3rd of April** (Monday). So this means the tree was wrapped in some big squared carton box (making it a cilinder, no top or bottom, so all good in this sense), **for 10 days**. The soil it came with (looks more like coconut fiber or peat) and it's still moist. But all the leaves look quite bad. Is this going to recover?

I know avocado plants are very sensitive but also trees in general are more resistent than their younger version (plants).

[image]

[image]

Before transplanting it into a 40x40x40cm, I´d like to know how to proceed beforehand:

1. Is it some kind of "shock" and it will recover with some time? If so, should I not put it under direct light, and once recovered, transplant it and direct sunlight?
2. Should I place it to direct sunlight? Should I use a lightlamp with red and blue light (It also comes with white light) to help it recover?

Comment: if it won't recover you might, depending on local laws and the seller or marketplace's policies, also be able to request a refund or replacement. This is just a bog-standard case of "goods damaged during shipping" no different than receiving an appliance with parts broken off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might recover...place in diffuse light, water when it dries out and hope for the best.  As it comes back move to higher light.

What you will see is that some of the leaves will not come back and can be removed when they dry out.  Avocados will bud out from the top again so you will end up with a skinny tree with a puff of leaves on the top.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I also contacted the place where I bought it (a "nursery") and they just replied! They told me to transplant it to soil or a bigger pot (I was going to do it after a few days of the plant to adapt) and put in straight onto sunlight so new healthy leaves can grow... No transition of lower light then brighter... Which seems strange to me. I am not sure if they are telling me this to "shut me up and calm me" or if it's really no problem...

Comment: @M.K - They're telling you to shut up

Comment: I think I can surely say now that it survived and it happened as you stated! One branch seems like it has died? Might add an edit to the question with an update